# I am getting this error and I can't find what is happening

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code

### I am using visual studio code!

Error

> Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file <

Starting build...
Build finished with error:

```
d:/win builds/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:c:\Users\p_mit\Desktop\helloworld\.vscode\tasks.json: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
d:/win builds/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:c:\Users\p_mit\Desktop\helloworld\.vscode\tasks.json:1: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.

tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:\\Win Builds\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "D:\\Win Builds\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: \"D:\\Win Builds\\bin\\gcc.exe\""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Post your `tasks.json` file as the error msg clearly states there is a syntax error in that.

Comment: Ok I edited it!

Comment: Oh, it looks like you have `tasks.json` opened and are trying to compile that.

Comment: If you're fussing a lot with Visual Studio Code you may find Visual Studio Community, which is a more compiler-focused environment, is a lot easier to get going with, especially for complex builds.